# CSS scroll hide overflow

Tags: html, css, web

I currently have [this website](https://seguramente.ml/).

Which produces the current output:
[image: normal]

But when I scroll, this happens:
[image: scrolled]

Any suggestions? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
To be more specific, the problem is the option appearing over the header when I scroll. The scrollbar is hidden on purpose.

The header is styled as position: sticky if that is of any help (check the link at the beginning for the preview, code is available at devtools)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: @ShawnW not really, I already have hidden the scrollbar. My issue is the text at the top of the question when I scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `padding: 10px` from your `.qa-container` class and add `border: 10px solid #fff` to your `.question` class and then add `padding: 0 10px` to your `.answers` class.